# Can't switch interpreter when using virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Using `django` and trying to run `manage.py` I get `import error` as `manage.py` is being run by the base interpreter which is looking in base directory where no django package exists.

When using virtualenv `python.exe`, there is no problem, however I can't get the virtualenv to switch to the `python.exe` I want.

I ran `virtualenv --no-site-packages -p C:\python27\virtualenvs\django12env\scripts\python.exe` and got back `Running virtualenv with interpreter C:\python27\virtualenvs\django12\scripts\python.exe Using real prefix 'C:\\Python27' New python executable in django12env\Scripts\python.exe Installing setuptools...`

However it still isn't using the interpreter I want.

I also don't understand why virtual environment would use an global interpreter in the first place, rather than the local interpreter it installs. I thought their entire purpose was to act as a sandbox?

Comment: **Don't** use the `-p` switch with a Python executable that already is in another virtualenv.

Comment: Could you elaborate? How do switch do the interpreter I want, and why isn't what I was trying to do not correct?

Comment: Maybe you forget to pick the name of your virtualenv. Try run `virtualenv --no-site-packages -p C:\python27\virtualenvs\django12env\scripts\python.exe venv`  Then, run `source venv/bin/activate`

Comment: Good guess. Added specifier `django12env` at the end, but still uses the base interpreter. Will just have to restart from the scratch.